# React TS При выведении списка товаров через map производит ошибка

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-типы

Мне нужно вывести карточки товара с сервера, которым задаю типизацию Product через TS:.

```
export interface Product{
  id: number
  title: string
  description: string[]
  rating: number
  price: number
  image: string
}
```

Импортирую и кидаю этот Products в запрос

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Heading from "../../components/Headling/Heading";
import ProductCard from "../../components/ProductCard/ProductCard";
import Search from "../../components/Search/Search";
import { PREFIX } from "../../helper/APi";
import { Product } from "../../interface/product.interface";
import styles from './Menu.module.css';

 export default function Menu(){

    const [products, setProducts] = useState<Product[]>([])

    const getMenu = async() => {

        try {
            const res = await fetch(PREFIX + '/products')

            if (!res.ok){
                return
            }
 
            const data = await res.json() as Product[];
            console.log(data)
            setProducts(data)
            
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e)
            return
        }

    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        getMenu()
    },[])

    return <>

        <div className={styles['head']}>
            <Heading>Меню</Heading>
            <Search placeholder="Введите блюдо или состав"/>
        </div>

        <div>
            {products.map( (p) => {
                <ProductCard 
                    key={p.id}
                    id = {p.id}
                    title={p.title}
                    description={p.description.join(', ')} 
                    rating={p.rating}
                    price={p.price}
                    image={p.image}
                />
            })}

        </div>
    </>
}
```

Данные получены, но почему-то когда я пытаюсь сделать список продуктов через {el.map}, то у меня не получается это сделать, потому что подчеркивается красным и выводится:

```
(property) ProductCardProps.title: string
Type 'void[]' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
  Type 'void[]' is not assignable to type 'Iterable<ReactNode>'.
    The types returned by '[Symbol.iterator]().next(...)' are incompatible between these types.
      Type 'IteratorResult<void, any>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<ReactNode, any>'.
        Type 'IteratorYieldResult<void>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<ReactNode, any>'.
          Type 'IteratorYieldResult<void>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorYieldResult<ReactNode>'.
            Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(2268, 9): The expected type comes from property 'children' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>'
```

Сама карточка(компонента)продукта(ProductCard)

```
import { ProductCardProps } from "./ProductCard.props";
import styles from './ProductCard.module.css';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function ProductCard(props:ProductCardProps){

    return(
        <Link to={`/product/${props.id}`}> 
            <div className={styles.card}>
                <div className={styles.head} style={{backgroundImage: `url('${props.image}')`}}>
                    <div className={styles.price}>
                        {props.price}
                        <span> ₽</span>
                    </div>
                    <button className={styles['add-to-card']}>
                        <img src="./menu/cart-card-btn.png" alt="добавить в корзину" />
                    </button>
                    <div className={styles['rating']}>
                        {props.rating}
                        <img src="./menu/rating.png" alt="иконка звезды" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.footer}>
                    <div className={styles['title']}>{props.title}</div>
                    <div className={styles['description']}>{props.description}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Link>
        
    )
}
```

Типизация карточки товара(компонента)(ProductCardProps)

```
export interface ProductCardProps{
    id: number;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    rating: number;
    price: number;
    image: string;
}
```

Настройки tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "Node", 
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true, 
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

Настройки tsconfig.node.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true
  },
  "include": ["vite.config.ts"]
}
```

типизация для переменных и компонентов должна быть правильной

Answer (score 0):

В общем, проблему я решил, НЕ ЗАБЫВАЙТЕ в map  написать return. Такая глупая ошибка(

Comment: Можно вместо return в map заменить фигурные скобки на круглые